# codenameone:We want to show the exact seconds of system on each seconds

Tags: codenameone

we are working on progress bar.we want to display exacts seconds of system on each seconds over progressbar.
 currently we are using java.util.Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance(); for getting system time .
 but its not working .
Can you please let me know how to resolve it. My application needs to be supported on all platforms (Andriod, IOS, windows) and I don't want to write native code for all platforms separately.

Comment: ...What language? Java? What code isn't working? Post more details and code. Also properly tag the question.

Comment: That gets you a Calendar object, how are you using the object to display time?

Comment: time=Calendar.getInstance().SECOND;                System.out.println("Display time"+time);

Comment: this is my code. i want to display time in each seconds on progress bar label and want to set progress dynamically grow with seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SECOND` is a `static final` value in Java and the same is true for Codename One so you are effectively trying to get the value of a constant that will never change...

`System.currentTimeMillis()` returns the system time from GMT in milliseconds.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
int currentSecond = c.get(Calendar.SECOND);
```

Also check this demo of a [live clock with animation](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/clock-demo.html) and code.